# JSON path extractor throws error when added to sampler

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to extract a token from response received in json. I have used jpgc-json-2.1 as well as jpgc-json-2.6 json plugin with JMeter. I am using JMeter version 2.13.

When I try to add a post processor to an HTTP sampler, I get this error in message box: `cannot find class:com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException`

I have added `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar` to lib and `jmeter-plugins-json-2.6.jar` and `jmeter-plugins-manager-0.11.jar` to ext folder.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried installing using plugin manager?https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager

Comment: Plugin manager is not working very well with JMeter 2.13. It launches but doesn't perform anything as its button is disabled too

Comment: I found a version with full plugins which might be helpful, here is the link https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeterforwindows/

Answer (score 1):

If you **have to** use JMeter 2.13 for some reason, you need to get the matching JSON Plugins version, in your case it would be [JMeterPlugins-ExtrasLibs-1.4.0.zip](https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-ExtrasLibs-1.4.0.zip) which you will need to install manually.

---

Be aware that JMeter 2.13 is a little bit outdated, it was released in March 2015 so it is 2+ years old for the moment so I would recommend updating to the latest JMeter version ([JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) as of now). Newer JMeter versions normally have new features (for instance [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)), bug fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I understand that I am using an older version but the file you have shared is the one I was looking for. I used to work with ExtraLibs. Fact of the matter is I have resumed JMeter after a lag of two years :)

Comment: I have also upgraded my JMeter to 3.1 as 3.2 .zip file seem to be broken as I downloaded it twice.

Comment: zip is not broken for me. What was the url and mirror you used ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 3.0, there is a native JSON extractor by default.
I would highly suggest you use JMeter 3.2 and this one.
No need for plugins here.

Comment: I am now already using native JSON extractor which is working fine. Thanks